# Library for displaying music notation

Tags: c#, xml, notation, musicxml

Is there a simple way, whether through a web service or just a library, to write/display music notation with C#? I have some data and am wondering if there is a way to show a staff with the given notes on it.

I've looked into MusicXML, but if I understand it correctly, it is purely a way to store the data - displaying it on a staff is a separate task. Short of manually using shapes (would be a lot of work) in HTML Canvas or WPF or what-have-you, is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Long list of background information and libraries for Java can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525959/are-there-any-music-notation-rendering-libraries-for-java.

A similar C# question can be found here: [Draw a music staff in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052598/draw-a-music-staff-in-c-sharp).

Here's an article describing how to show MusicXML notation with WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89582/PSAM-WPF-Control-Library.